# What is this code meaning...?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, laravel, static-functions

I want to put this question for me. To better understand **PHP** and **Laravel**.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is actually a method with a static function inside it? And inside of this static function another one...? I have to say i am a beginner with *Frameworks*.

This is my first time playing around with one.

Comment: `up()` triggers a "new Schema" - where I assume that Schema is either a component or a model in Laraval (never used it). The function inside that call is a [callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) - used to tell `Schema::create` what it should do with the results of its processing.

Comment: Also note that `create` is a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) of `Schema` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your confusion is more about how the code works rather than what it does, it's actually a pretty complex subject. First, it's not really a static method.

Laravel uses something call [Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades) that allows you to call methods "statically", which can be confusing for people new to the framework. In a nutshell, facades are a great convenience because when you call a method using Laravel's facade, it "masks" a ton of instance objects for you and then calls the method.

Lets take for example `Schema` in this instance. Where is this `Schema` class? If you look inside your `config/app.php` file, you'll see this line of code under aliases:

```
'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
```

`Schema` is therefore an alias for `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`.

So if you take a look at `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`, you'll see that it `extends Facade`. It is one of Laravel's facades. This directory has a ton of Laravel's facades. Anyway, at the top of this class, you'll also see a little convenient comment that says:

```
@see \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder
```

Open up that file, and this is your `Schema` class. Behind the scenes, Laravel instantiates this object for you. Why is this such a big deal? Take a look at the constructor. One of this class' dependencies is `Illuminate\Database\Connection`. Open up that class, and it has even more dependencies. Rather than having to manually instantiate all these classes all the time, facades do the work for you. So when you do `Schema::create(...`, Laravel is instantiating all these dependencies and calling the `create` method in the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` class. Pretty awesome, right? If you look in that file, you'll see the method:

```
/**
 * Create a new table on the schema.
 *
 * @param  string    $table
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint
 */
public function create($table, Closure $callback)
{
    $blueprint = $this->createBlueprint($table);

    $blueprint->create();

    $callback($blueprint);

    $this->build($blueprint);
}
```

You can see that it's **not** a static method. Laravel is creating a new instance behind the scenes and then calling the method.

The first argument accepts a string, which would be the name of the table you are creating. Then it accepts a closure. In this case, as @Kostas Mitsarakis said, you are creating a table that is called `tasks`. This table has an auto-incrementing column called `id`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was wondering how to works. Because i am always a little bit curious about how staff works. You covered at 100% my question.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a table `tasks` with `id` as `auto increment` column, `name` as `varchar` column and  `created_at` and `updated_at` as `timestamp` columns.

More info [**here**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema).